# pylint with a custom rcfile and the errors-only flag

Tags: python, pylint

Is it possible to run pylint with a custom rcfile *and* the errors-only flag?  I would like pylint to report warnings in typical usage, but when the check runs on our CI server, I'd like to use `--errors-only`.

For example, suppose I have test.py:

```
"""test.py -- a test of pylint's error-handling."""

def some_method():
    """Just a method."""
    print 'hi'
    return 2
```

and a custom pylintrc file which should suppress reports and the print statement error:

```
# custom-pylintrc

[REPORTS]
# Disable the reporting and just show messages.
reports=no

[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=print-statement
```

I get no errors when I use the pylintrc file on its own, but passing the flag shows an error that I expected to be suppressed by the rcfile.

```
$ pylint test.py --rcfile=custom-pylintrc  # passes with no output
$ pylint test.py --rcfile=custom-pylintrc --errors-only
************* Module test
E:  5, 4: print statement used (print-statement)
```

I guess I want to have my cake and eat it too -- can I use the rcfile and a flag?

Comment: You can also have a separate rc file for the CI, as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

CI can run a custom command that does not use the `pylintrc`:

`pylint --errors-only --disable=print-statement test.py`